# Excel: FREQUENCY function returns strange results

Tags: excel, statistics, histogram, frequency

I have 15 rows with some numeric data in each. I also have 4 intervals for which I want to calculate data's frequency. However when I do so using `FREQUENCY(data_array; intervals)` function the sum of returned frequences is 18, rather than 15.

Why is that so? Where is my mistake?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you have entered the formula as an array formula in C2, but then pulled it down into cells C3:C5.

You need to select C2:C6 (you need 5 cells altogether for 4 cut points), then use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter the formula [See documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FREQUENCY-function-44e3be2b-eca0-42cd-a3f7-fd9ea898fdb9).